# Foreign key 'fk_orders_SalesRep' references invalid column 'snum' in referencing table 'orders'

Tags: sql, sql-server

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to add a foreign key to an existing table

```sql
ALTER TABLE orders 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_orders_SalesRep
                  FOREIGN KEY (snum) 
                  REFERENCES SalesRep(snum);
```

Table information

```sql
create table SalesRep(
    snum varchar(5) primary key,
    sname varchar(10),
    hours Int 
)

create table orders(
    odId varchar(5) primary key,
    itId varchar(5) foreign key(itId) references items(itId)
)
```

Comment: your orders table has no column called snum. What column is supposed to be participating in the FK on that side? You need to add the column first

Comment: Oh, i thought by doing the alter table .... it would add the column my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Martin said add the column first

```
ALTER TABLE orders
ADD snum varchar(5);
```

And then add the fk

```
ALTER TABLE orders 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_orders_SalesRep
                  FOREIGN KEY (snum) 
                  REFERENCES SalesRep(snum);
```